# Import .spv file into R / convert into .csv

Tags: r, spss

I want to import an .spv file into R but I cannot find a way to do it. I tried using the "haven" package but it seems it only supports .sav. Does anyone know how to do this? The end goal is to transform the .spv file into a .csv/.xlsx file so if you know of other ways that would also be super helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know the `.spv` file extension. Do you know if the file is binary or text-based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `.spv` contains the analysis results from SPSS, including text, figure, and table(literal); it is binary. While the `.sav` file is the dataset, you can think of it as a data frame. That's why `haven` could have `read_sav()` and `write_sav`.

There are some fundamental differences between them. The behavior of importing the `.spv` file is very unclear. Like, what info are you trying to extract? Is it text, figure, or table?

I would convert `.spv` file to Word first, and confirm what info I like to extract first. If it is text, save it as `.txt` file. If it is a table, save it as `.csv` file manually. I assume there is no need for the figure as you want to convert it to `.csv`.

Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yrq19b4kkec) how to convert `.spv` to `.docx`. Hope it helps.